# Haxe / Openfl/ Is it possible to load a video (.mp4) from the Assets file and display it in the stage?

Tags: haxe, openfl

Why does Haxe have such poor documentation" Why are there no examples at all?

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the platform you're targeting to.

OpenFL can play videos on HTML5, however, it cannot play them natively (Windows, macOS, Linux).
For native platforms, consider searching for a library.

If you're targeting a native platform, as Ilir Liburn said, use [hxCodec](https://lib.haxe.org/p/hxCodec).
If not, check out the [PlayingVideo](https://github.com/openfl/openfl-samples/blob/master/features/media/PlayingVideo/Source/Main.hx) example OpenFL provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check libraries to see if there is something available like

https://lib.haxe.org/p/hxCodec